# How do I set the value of a variable using a switch statement with an expression that is a variable set as a dom elements id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

The problem I have is that I am trying to set a variable(contentUrl) that i can use to specify the URL for my ajax injected dom element. So when I drag and drop an item it loads another element from a different page through the ".load()" method. Currently I am trying to use a switch statement to set my contentUrl variable.

The other point of contention is the fact that the .load() method, as specified in the jQuery API, requires the url to be a string.

What can i do to set my contentUrl based on the value of CurDragItem and then execute an ajax .load method to return an element from a page with the value of contentUrl? If this is not possible with a switch and the .load method –like i assume it isn't- how can i achieve what I just described?

Let me know if you need me to put it in a fiddle. Again I am using jQuery UI's dnd widget to accomplish this nonesense.

Heres a snippet of my code:

```
$(function() {
                var dragItems = $('.sidebar-listItem');
                var dropArea = $('.drop');
                var sidebarWrap = $('#l-sidebar-wrapper');
                var sidebarList = $("#l-sidebar-list");

                var contentList = $('.main-content-list');


                dragItems.draggable({ 
                    cursor: "move",
                    cursorAt: {top:60, left:45},
                    helper: 'clone',  
                    revert: "invalid",
                    scroll: false,
                    appendTo: 'body'
                        });
                // setter
                dragItems.draggable( "option", "scroll", false );       

                dropArea.droppable({
                    accept: ".sidebar-listItem",
                    activeClass: "dogs",
                    hoverClass: "dogs",
                    drop: function() {
                            //set the curDragItem value to the id of the element that is being dragged
                             var curDragItem = $('.ui-draggable-dragging').attr("id");
                             //initialize the variable with the value of nothing 
                             var contentUrl = "nothing";

                            //use switch statement to check whether curDragItem matches a case and then set value of contentURL
                            switch (curDragItem) {
                            case 'hour24-1':
                            contentUrl = "hour24.html";
                            break;
                            case 'matisyahu':
                            contentUrl = "matisyahu.html";
                            break;
                            case 'dirtyheads':
                            contentUrl = "dirtyHeads.html";
                            break;
                            }
                            //check what the value of contentUrl is
                            console.log(contentUrl);

                        //load the .main-content-list from a page with the url that is the value of contentUrl

                        dropArea.load("value of contentUrl .main-content-list", initDynamicEventHandlers);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Does `dropArea.load(contentUrl + " .main-content-list", initDynamicEventHandlers);` fail?

Comment: you can use an object as a look-up-table instead of switch() for 1-in-1-out lineups. in that way, the compare logic runs faster, is iterable, and can be used from many functions if needed.

Comment: @dehrg Actually I think it would work. Now it's just a matter of making the contentUrl change its value depending on the value of curDragItem.

Answer (score 0):

As dandavis mentioned in the comments, your best bet would probably be an object mapper in case you need to use it elsewhere in the application.

Aside from that, you can add parameters to the drop function as mentioned in the [jQuery UI docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) so that you have access to whatever object was dropped.

```
                var dropArea = $('.drop');
            var sidebarWrap = $('#l-sidebar-wrapper');
            var sidebarList = $("#l-sidebar-list");

            var contentList = $('.main-content-list');
            var mapper = {
              'hour24-1': 'hour24.html',
              'matisyahu': 'matisyahu.html',
              'dirtyheads': 'dirtyHeads.html'
            };


            dragItems.draggable({ 
                cursor: "move",
                cursorAt: {top:60, left:45},
                helper: 'clone',  
                revert: "invalid",
                scroll: false,
                appendTo: 'body'
                    });
            // setter
            dragItems.draggable( "option", "scroll", false );       

            dropArea.droppable({
                accept: ".sidebar-listItem",
                activeClass: "dogs",
                hoverClass: "dogs",
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                        //set the curDragItem value to the id of the element that is being dragged
                         var curDragItem = ui.attr("id"); // Use the passed in parameter
                         //initialize the variable with the value of nothing 
                         var contentUrl = "nothing";

                        //check the value of curDragItem
                        console.log('Drag item: ' + curDragItem);
                        contentUrl = mapper[curDragItem];
                        //check what the value of contentUrl is
                        console.log(contentUrl);

                    //load the .main-content-list from a page with the url that is the value of contentUrl                 
                    dropArea.load(contentUrl + " .main-content-list", initDynamicEventHandlers);
                }
            });
        });

...
```

Comment: I added the code as you have written and contentUrl just comes up as undefined.

Comment: and it does the same thing with the switch statement.

Comment: yeah, curDragItem is an id of the list item that is currently being dragged. When a list item is dragged it is given the class: "ui-draggable-dragging." So I want to compare the id of the dragged item with class "ui-draggable-dragging" to a list of ids to determine if it's a match. If it is a match contentUrl is given the value of a corresponding url and the dropArea will load a ul from a page with the class "main-content-list" into itself.

Comment: Like with a console.log()?

Comment: on Initialization the curDragItem is undefined. So it would seem that's part of the problem. So theres nothing to compare to in the mapper. The possible reason for that might be because the dragged item isn't being assigned the ui-draggable-dragging class until an item is dragged. In short the item doesn't exist until the drag starts. Not really sure what to do about that, but i'll do some reading.